# Haskell: make int list of lists out of a single string

Tags: string, haskell, functional-programming

I've got some data in txt file which looks like this:

```
  [Just 3, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Nothing] [Nothing, Just 3, Nothing, Nothing]
```

What I need is to have list of lists containing above values as integers e.g.

```
[[3,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],....]
```

And so on. Do you have any idea how to do it properly? I can replace "nothing" by 0 and drop "Just" part but it will stay as a single string.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is probably to use a parser library like `Text.Parsec`.  That being said, here's a quick and hacky way to do it not unlike what a python programmer might come up with. The idea is to massage the input string into a form that `read` will parse for us.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Prelude hiding (null)
import Data.Text (snoc, pack, unpack, splitOn, strip, null)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import System.IO

parse :: String -> [[Maybe Int]]
parse = map read . map unpack . map (flip snoc ']') . filter (not . null) . map strip . splitOn "]" . pack

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- readFile "myfile.txt"  -- input = "[Just 3, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Nothing] [Nothing, Just 3, Nothing, Nothing]"
  putStrLn . show $ map (map (fromMaybe 0)) (parse input)
```

The `parse` method works like this:

- `pack` converts a `String` value into a `Text` value
- `splitOn "]"` does exactly what you think
- `map strip` removes leading and trailing whitespace
- `filter (not . null)` removes empty strings (there's one at the end)
- `map (flip snoc ']')` append the "]" character back to the end of each string
- `map unpack` converts each `Text` value back to a `String` value
- `map read` parses each `String` value into a `[Maybe Int]`

Comment: You define input as a list of string lists. In my case I get single string from file and that's the main problem.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: That's impresive but it looks like I'm still getting IO type (or string) and what I needed was [[int]]

Comment: @Dominik if you're reading from a file, there is no way to escape `IO`, you have to work inside it.

Comment: Whoa, why is that? There is no any trick? Safety is not main goal.

Comment: @Dominik I cannot, in good conscience, tell you about `performUnsafeIO`. I think you should really just work inside `IO`.  I adjusted my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: So maybe to be able to iterate on specific values I should use my own type? In that file in front of all was word "pyramid" and then [....

Comment: I don't know what you mean by use your own type. You can either use `Data.Text` functions to transform the input into a form that `read` will parse for you as I did above, or you can learn how to use a parser library like `Text.Parsec`.

Comment: I mean this

    http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses
Is it possible, to simply make my own type and fill it with values retreived from file as above (pyramid [some data])? I prefer to ask even before trying because google did not return any available solution.

Comment: I see.  You want to make a data type and derive `Read`. That will not work unless the format of your string is the exact format that the derived `Read` instance is expecting. It can't magically know what format your data is in.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate version that uses `read`:

```
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Data.Maybe      (fromMaybe)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    s <- readFile "lists.txt"
    let xs = map (\s' -> map (fromMaybe 0) (read (s' ++ "]"))) . init . splitOn "]" $ s
    print xs
```

The idea is simple: first, the file contents are read as a `String` and bound to `s`. Then, `s` is parsed to a list of integers (`[Int]`) which is bound to `xs`. In order to do that, the following steps are taken:

1. `splitOn "]"`: splits the input string `s` generating a list of strings (`[String]`). Each element misses the character `']'` in the end. The last element of this list is an undesirable `"\n"`. The resulting list is:

   ```
   ["[Just 3, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing"," [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing", ..., "\n"]
   ```
2. `init`: removes the unwanted "\n".
3. `map (\s' -> map (fromMaybe 0) (read (s' ++ "]")))`: applies to each string element the enclosed lambda function, which does:

   1. `read (s' ++ "]")`: append the missing `']'` to the string and parses it to a list of `Maybe`s (`Num a => [Maybe a]`). Note that we do not need to explicitly specify a type for `read` because GHC can infer it from the use of `fromMaybe 0` (see below).
   2. `map (fromMaybe 0)`: apply the function `fromMaybe 0` on each element of the list, which returns `v` when `Just v`; and `0`, otherwise.

That way you can get a list of integer lists using `read`.